Android AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume: call on background Thread to avoid ANR?
I use the following code to increase music volume when the user presses the VolumeUp button:
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    }
}

In the Google Developer Console, I'm seeing this ANR:

This Binder call may be taking too long, causing the main thread to
wait, and triggering the ANR.
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.iava: 1154)
at android.media.IAudioServiceSStub$Proxy.adjustStreamVolume (IAudioService.java: 1150)
at android.media.AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume (AudioManager.java: 820)
at com.example.MyActivity.onKeyDown (MyActivity.java:42)

Your app's code results in the Binder call above. Code that triggers
Binder calls should be moved out of the main thread.

Should calls to AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume be performed on a background Thread?
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        new Thread(this::increaseVolume).start();
        return true;
    }
}

private void increaseVolume() {
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
}


Directly creating a new thread in onKeyDown to call AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume is not a good approach. Thread creation and management is resource consuming process and here its not necessary. Accessing the AudioManager instance from a background thread might lead to synchronization issues if you're modifying other UI elements related to volume control.

Your onKeyDown method directly calls AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume on the main thread. This method might involve communication with the audio service, which can be a Binder call and might take some time. Blocking the main thread for a long-running operation like this can lead to ANRs if the UI thread becomes unresponsive. Alternatively use Handler or CoroutineDispatcher for background tasks.
